# How to make a np array of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, 3d

Hey all i imagine this could have been answered however I can not find what i'm looking for exactly. Here is the code bellow:

```
positiveData = np.array([])
negativeData = []

with AedatFile('someFile') as f:
    # loop through the "frames" stream
    for e in f['events'].numpy():
        for event in e:
            time, x, y, polarity, _, _ = event
            if polarity == 1:
                data = np.array([time, x, y, polarity])
                print(data)
                positiveData = np.append(positiveData,data)
                print(positiveData)
            else:
                data = [time, x, y, polarity]
                negativeData.append(data)
```

I am expecting the code to look like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[1,2,3,4],
....]
```

I plan on using this to make a 3d plot so i want an array so i can easily plot3d(array[0][:],array[1][:],array[2][:])

cheers all.

Here is the a sample set of data that was asked for below. I cant paste more as it says my comment is mostly code and wont allow me to post more without adding more text which incredibly stupid.

```
[(1612584805989190, 254, 304, 1, 0, 0)
 (1612584805989190, 254, 283, 1, 0, 0)
 (1612584805989190, 254, 286, 1, 0, 0) ...
 (1612584805999148, 596,  20, 1, 0, 0)
 (1612584805999162, 549,  60, 1, 0, 0)
 (1612584805999189, 461, 225, 0, 0, 0)]
[(1612584806009235, 512,  31, 1, 0, 0)
 (1612584806009263, 419, 274, 1, 0, 0)
 (1612584806009287, 338, 188, 0, 0, 0) ...
 (1612584806019188, 214, 241, 0, 0, 0)
 (1612584806019188, 214, 237, 0, 0, 0)
 (1612584806019189, 211, 234, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: If you need to iterate, use list append as you do with `negativeData`.  `np.append` is hard to use right, and slower.  If you have a list of lists (all the same size), `np.array(alist)` should create the required 2d array.

Comment: So one thing i did was append it all as a list then made it an np.array after 

data = [x, y, time, polarity]
                positiveData.append(data)
positiveData = np.array(positiveData)

which will get me what i want however i feel like this could be faster? As it is 2GB of data and is chunking through VERY slow. 60-90sec for a single run maybe more

Comment: If you have to iterate through files and 'events', the array build part of the task will be minor.  There are fast ways of building arrays fron othdr arrays, if you can avoid python level iteration.  There are many SO questions about making arrays iteratively

Comment: what is the `type` of `f['events'].numpy()`?  Is it a `numpy` array?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying to

```
positiveData = np.append( positiveData, [data] )
```

or

```
data = np.array( [[ time, x, y, polarity ]] )
```

The append function will append (embed) the array given to inside the array target
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html